# Dereferencing a reference in a function argument

Tags: c++, pointers, recursion, reference

In the following website:

[Link](http://leetcode.com/2010/09/serializationdeserialization-of-binary.html)

they discuss how to deserialize a binary tree. I can successfully implement the methods described but I am getting stuck on why the first parameter/argument to the function:

```
void readBinaryTree(BinaryTree *&p, ifstream &fin)
```

is written as `BinaryTree *&p`. More specifically, I don't understand why we must dereference the reference to `p`. Any clarification would be greatly appreciated.

If one were to re-write the function, would it look like this instead?

```
void readBinaryTree(BinaryTree &p, ifstream &fin) {
  int token;
  bool isNumber;
  if (!readNextToken(token, fin, isNumber)) 
    return;
  if (isNumber) {
    p = new BinaryTree(token);
    readBinaryTree(p.left, fin);
    readBinaryTree(p.right, fin);
  }
}
```

Is this correct?

Comment: so ugly... thanks C++

Comment: `p` is a reference to a *pointer* - to - `BinaryTree`; not a reference to a `BinaryTree`.

Comment: You are not "dereferencing the reference". You can't "dereference" a reference. And what you have here is not a statement or expression either, it doesn't "do" anything -- it's just a declaration. It declares the argument to be a reference to a pointer to a `BinaryTree`.

Comment: Looks very weird to one new to `C++` coming from `C`.

Answer (score 2):

```
void readBinaryTree(BinaryTree *&p, ifstream &fin)
```

Here, `p` is a reference to a pointer (an existing pointer in memory that points at a `BinaryTree`), **NOT** a reference to the `BinaryTree` itself. Without the `&` operator, the pointer `p` would be passed by value (the pointer is copied) when the function is invoked.

Answer (score 1):

The parameter `p` is a reference to a `BinaryTree` pointer. The function uses `new` to give `p` a value and hence pass it back to whatever code is calling it.

i.e.

```
readBinsaryTreee(x, ...)
// Now x will point the the binary tree created by the function `readBinaryTree`
```